# How to call controller/action in zend framework via jquery/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

How to call controller/action in zend framework via jquery/ajax?

I tried this

```
<script>
     $(function() {
         $(".tbl_repeat tbody").tableDnD({
            onDrop: function(table, row) {
            var orders = $.tableDnD.serialize();
            $.post("<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/Indexcodelist/indexcodelistsearch/",{order : orders });
    }
    });
 });
 </script>
```

this code isn't calling the controller's action method, how do i achieve it?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: getting no value in the controller in the line:

$item_order = $request->getParam('order');
print_r($item_order);

Comment: Try to `console.log(orders);` before `$.post(...)`

Comment: still getting no value in the controller.

Comment: Have you get anything in your `browser's console`??

Comment: yes i'm getting the value of $item_order and the url sent in the post method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66901/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-kapil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem occurred that we have to use single or double quotes when giving the name of passing data in `$.post(...)` or `$.ajax(...)` otherwise it interpret it as an javascript object not a name.

```
$.post("<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/Indexcodelist/indexcodelistsearch/",{'order':orders});
                                                                            ^-----^
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way to work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('a.validate').click(function(){
        //alert($(this).attr('href'));
        $.post('/application/object/validate',{type:'type', id:$(this).attr('href'), pkObject:$('#pkObject').val()},function(data){
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps.